What does the '!' button do?
Clicking the exclamation mark button makes it light up in red, but other than that I'm not sure what's happening.  The tutorial notably didn't mention this feature at all.


Each time your castle takes damage (up to 4850 damages), the bulb on the side of this button fills up with gas, allowing you to use the "!" button. This launches a capacity called ARG, which gives your next wave of units some health, armor, and shield boosts. The more you wait for this bulb to be filled, the higher the bonuses will be.
